# Java Spark- How to call UDF with multiple column as argument

Tags: java, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to execute the following code

```
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("test")
        .master("local")
      //.enableHiveSupport()
        .getOrCreate();

StructField[] structFields = new StructField[]{
        new StructField("FIRST", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
        new StructField("SECOND", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty())
};

StructType structType = new StructType(structFields);

List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();
rows.add(RowFactory.create("1","2"));
rows.add(RowFactory.create("2","3"));
Dataset<Row> dataDs = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rows, structType);
UDF1 mode = new UDF1<String,String, String>() {

    public String call(String a,String b) throws Exception {
        return a+b;
    }

};
sparkSession.udf().register("mode",mode,DataTypes.StringType);
dataDs.withColumn("newCol",callUDF("mode",col("FIRST"),col("SECOND")));
dataDs.show();
```

However, it seems I can't declare the UDF with multiple arguments as I did with

```
UDF1 mode = new UDF1<String,String, String>() {
    public String call(String a,String b) throws Exception {
        return a+b;
    }
 };
```

I want to pass both my columns as input to UDF.

I can pass a single object in first param like Integer or something, but I want to pass multiple columns. How should I do it? Can someone help me out here? I have been searching the internet for this but not able to find a solution. I am new to spark.

Comment: The function interfaces are named differently based on the number of arguments. So you need to make it `UDF2 mode = new UDF2<String, String, String>() {...}`

Comment: Oh. I see. I didn't knew that. I am new to spark. Thanks. I will try that out.

Comment: Just a note: you can shorten the code by using a lambda expression: `UDF2<String, String, String> mode = (a, b) -> a + b;` (if you're on Java 8+)

Comment: Thanks. I actually want to invoke a complex code inside this UDF, so don't think lambda will help in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally agree with @emest_k's comments and want to add one more thing. Because dataFrame is immutable so that you need to use new dataFrame to see output using show(). Here is an sample.

```
{
    ...

    UDF2 mode = new UDF2<String, String, String>() {
        public String call(String a, String b) throws Exception {
            return a + b;
        }
    };
    sparkSession.udf().register("mode", mode, DataTypes.StringType);
    Dataset<Row> newDataFrame = dataDs.withColumn("newCol", callUDF("mode", col("FIRST"), col("SECOND")));
    newDataFrame.show();
}
```